# Python - Can you explain this while-loop for me?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please help me understand the logic in this while loop?
bear_room() is defined. The bear is in front of the door to begin with bear_moved = False. I don't understand why the loops needs to begin with while True:. bear_room() begins as False, so why would the code enter the loop to begin? Shouldn't the loop begin with while False (I tried that too)? The logic seems backwards to me. I tried removing the while loop and just asking for user input.

This is just part of the code so please ignore calls to other functions...

```
def bear_room():
    print ("There is a bear here.")
    print ("The bear has a bunch of honey.")
    print ("The fat bear is in front of another door.")
    print ("How are you going to move the bear?")
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        choice = input("> ")

        if choice == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print ("The bear has moved from the door.")
            print ("You can go through it now.")
            bear_moved = True
        elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your legs off.")
        elif choice == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print ("I got no idea what that means.")
```

Comment: You might be under the impression that `while True:` means "while the last variable that was defined before this loop is true". You would then expect the loop to never execute, since `bear_moved` isn't True. But that is not how `while True:` works. It doesn't care about the state of `bear_moved` at all. If you want the loop to continue as long as `bear_moved` is False, you need to do `while bear_moved == False`.

Answer (score 2):

`while True` simply means that the while loop will repeat forever until something breaks it. Because `True` will always be true it will keep going.

I don't understand where this is supposed to break though so that is just your call!

EDIT: Something that other people have pointed out is if you actually want to escape the loop without a `break` call then simply set the condition of the `while` loop to be `while bear_moved == false`. That way when the bear moves and sets `bear_moved`to `True` then the while loop will stop running.

Comment: I guess method `dead` will be responsible of breaking the loop.

Comment: I would assume that too! :D

Comment: But you can't break a loop unless you're directly inside the loop. If `dead` calls `break`, that would be a `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`. I guess `dead` could call `sys.exit`, but that's not so much breaking the loop as it is breaking the entire program.

Comment: He said to ignore the method calls but that would be true yeah. I just used break as an example for use inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

The While True is going to loop forever as I don't see any break in the code.  Maybe I misunderstand the code but I don't see any relation with bear_room()

Comment: While  condition:  repeats until condition no met

Answer (score 0):

`while True:` means to run the loop forever, or until a `break` is encountered. The value `True` has nothing to do with the variable `bear_moved`. Your current loop will run forever unless a `sys.exit()` exists in one of the called functions since there is no 'break'.